# getting error while using the dyanmic variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript

In HTML I am declaring like this, I am getting list of dynamic variables from DB

```
eval('var ' + result.Symbols + ';')// result.Symbols will have S1,S2,S3,S4,S5
```

up to this it is working fine

In .js i am trying to use this

```
eval(calRulelist[i].RuleReference) == calRulelist[i].RuleValue
```

here `calRulelist[i].RuleReference` is S1 on evaluation it will give O/P '5' and compare with the `calRulelist[i].RuleValue`

Here it is throwing error S1 is undefined.

If I declared normally like var S1,S2,S3,S4,S5; working fine.

Comment: why you require eval here "eval(calRulelist[i].RuleReference) == calRulelist[i].RuleValue "??

Comment: Why are you using eval in the first place? Something like this would probably work better with storing the data on-page with JSON (assuming it's coming from backend code) and then parsing said JSON with Javascript. But I think your issue is due to the order in which JS interprets eval statements.

Comment: Not sure how your code work but your first line declare variable but without any value. Even without eval() ```var S1;``` would make S1 undefined. And you could avoid eval all together by just storing them against an object and using the Symbols as key.

Comment: i need to compare the like this if (eval(calRulelist[i].RuleReference) == calRulelist[i].RuleValue) {//satisfies the rule }

Comment: @gillesc makes a good point, it will be undefined regardless of what you do because the variable is... well... undefined!